# Cannot extend MUI-Material ListItemButtonProps with custom additional props... TypeScript error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

This should be an easy task. I want a custom component inherits all props from `ListItemButtonProps`, adding an additional `state` prop:

```ts
type SidebarListItemButtonProps = ListItemButtonProps & {
  state: SidebarState,
};

const SidebarListItemButton = ({ state, children, ...props }: SidebarListItemButtonProps) => (
  <ListItemButton {...props} sx={{
    ...props.sx,
    ...((!state.open && state.collapsed) && { 
      justifyContent: 'center', 
    }),
  }}>
    {children}
  </ListItemButton>
);
```

This *seems* to work fine util you pass the `component` prop:

```
<SidebarListItemButton state={{ open, collapsed }} component={RouterLink} to='/'>
  <ListItemText primary='Home' />
</SidebarListItemButton>
```

> Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListItemButtonBaseProps & Omit<{ action?: Ref | undefined; ... 13 more ...; touchRippleRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; }, "classes"> & CommonProps & Omit<...> & { ...; }'.

Anyone does know why this is happening and how to solve this TypeScript issue?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's no problem with how you're passing the props.

I tried the same thing in a new project.

I do get the same error when I pass a component link like `NextLink` from `next/link`.

Like this:

```
import Link from "next/link";

<ListItemButton component={NextLink} />
```

However, If I pass in the `Link` component from `mui` there's no error.

```
import { Link, ListItemButton } from "@mui/material";

<ListItemButton component={Link} />
```

So I believe your error is with `RouterLink` being the wrong type and not the type of the prop.

Comment: Unfortunatly `component` prop works fine if used with plain` ListItemButton` :(